# Скрипт не видит выполненного условия или не отправляет запрос

Tags: javascript

Вообщем, скрипт никак не хочет выполнять то, что идёт после условия, даже если условие выполнено. Не могу понять причину, код:

```
var str = window.location.search.replace( '?', '');
        var ver;
                    //Тут объявляется нужная переменная
        if(str == ""){
            document.querySelector("#llogin").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#lllogin").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#mail").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#phone").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#password").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#repass").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#binding").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector("#button").className = "hidden";
            document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = "Произошла неизвестная ошибка";
        }else{
        $.post("profile.php", {"str": str},
            function(data){
                if(data == "true"){
                    ver = null;
                    ver = true;
                                            //Тут устанавливается значение true
                }else if(data == "false"){
                    ver = null;
                    ver = false;
                    document.querySelector("#llogin").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#lllogin").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#mail").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#phone").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#password").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#repass").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#binding").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector("#button").className = "hidden";
                    document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = "Для начала необходимо пройти <br> процесс Авторизации";
                }
            });
        if(ver == true){
                    //Даже если ver == true, дальнейшие действия не происходят
            $.post("profile.php", {"login": str},
                function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    document.querySelector(".llogin").innerHTML = data;
                }
            );
```

Проблема именно с условием, помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете вот этот кусок

```
if (ver == true) {
  ...
}
```

и переносите в

```
$.post("profile.php", {"str": str},
  function(data) {
    // ...
    // сюда
});
```